# href não executa jQuery e nem function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Ao clicar no link Responder o código não executa, não mostra o alert do jQuery e nem da function, tbm não mostra erro no console, não chega nem a executar.

```
$('#post-forum').last().append('<div><a href="#" id="responder" >Responder</a></div>');

$('#responder').on('click', function (event) {
    // alert('teste');
    teste();
    event.preventDefault();
});

function teste() {
 alert('teste');
}
```

Comment: Tente mudar a primeira linha assim: `$('#post-forum').last().append('<div id="responder"><a href="#" >Responder</a></div>');`

Comment: Obrigado, acabei de tentar, e tbm não funcionou, ele tenta pegar o valor do href.

Answer (score 1):

Eu reparei que estás a apontar um `.last()` para um `id` na primeira linha do teu código, o que mais certamente deverá ser a razão pelo qual o código não está a executar.

> `id`'s são para ser utilizados apenas uma única vez no DOM.
>   Para identificar mais que um elemento com o mesmo nome, devemos utilizar `classes`.

```js
$('.post-forum').last().append('<div><a href="#" id="responder" >Responder</a></div>');

$('#responder').on('click', function (event) {
    // alert('teste');
    teste();
    event.preventDefault();
});

function teste() {
    alert('teste');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-forum">1</div>
<div class="post-forum">2</div>
<div class="post-forum">3</div>
```